# Cannot subscribe to a private or presence channel because no Authorizer has been set. Call PusherOptions.setAuthorizer() before connecting to Pusher

Tags: laravel, flutter, pusher, broadcasting, laravel-events

In a chat application,

`Laravel 7.x`,
`Vuejs 2`,
`Flutter 2.8` and `Pusher`

Pacakges I use `pusherjs`, `Laravel echo`, `pusher-php-server` and `Flutter pusher_client`.

in `Laravel & Vue` public and private channels work fine, in with `Flutter` public channel also working but, subscribing to `private` channel show the following error.

```
Cannot subscribe to a private or presence channel because no Authorizer has been set. Call PusherOptions.setAuthorizer() before connecting to Pusher
W/System.err(10758): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot subscribe to a private or presence channel because no Authorizer has been set. Call PusherOptions.setAuthorizer() before connecting to Pusher
W/System.err(10758):    at com.pusher.client.Pusher.throwExceptionIfNoAuthorizerHasBeenSet(Pusher.java:376)
W/System.err(10758):    at com.pusher.client.Pusher.subscribePrivate(Pusher.java:281)
W/System.err(10758):    at com.github.chinloyal.pusher_client.pusher.PusherService.subscribe(PusherService.kt:152)
W/System.err(10758):    at com.github.chinloyal.pusher_client.pusher.PusherService.access$subscribe(PusherService.kt:30)
W/System.err(10758):    at com.github.chinloyal.pusher_client.pusher.PusherService$register$1.onMethodCall(PusherService.kt:56)
W/System.err(10758):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
W/System.err(10758):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:178)
W/System.err(10758):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$handleMessageFromDart$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:206)
W/System.err(10758):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$R4HPk6oFVb-i-YR_PN9YE6kqx1I.run(Unknown Source:12)
W/System.err(10758):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
W/System.err(10758):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
W/System.err(10758):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
W/System.err(10758):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
W/System.err(10758):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(10758):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
W/System.err(10758):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
D/PusherClientPlugin(10758): Event stream cancelled.
D/PusherClientPlugin(10758): Event stream listening...
D/PusherClientPlugin(10758): [BIND] chat-event
E/flutter (10758): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(SUBSCRIBE_ERROR, Cannot subscribe to a private or presence 
channel because no Authorizer has been set. Call PusherOptions.setAuthorizer() before connecting to Pusher, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot subscribe to a private or presence channel because no Authorizer has been set. Call PusherOptions.setAuthorizer() before connecting to Pusher
E/flutter (10758):      at com.pusher.client.Pusher.throwExceptionIfNoAuthorizerHasBeenSet(Pusher.java:376)
E/flutter (10758):      at com.pusher.client.Pusher.subscribePrivate(Pusher.java:281)
E/flutter (10758):      at com.github.chinloyal.pusher_client.pusher.PusherService.subscribe(PusherService.kt:152)
E/flutter (10758):      at com.github.chinloyal.pusher_client.pusher.PusherService.access$subscribe(PusherService.kt:30)
E/flutter (10758):      at com.github.chinloyal.pusher_client.pusher.PusherService$register$1.onMethodCall(PusherService.kt:56)
E/flutter (10758):      at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/flutter (10758):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:178)
E/flutter (10758):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$handleMessageFromDart$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:206)
E/flutter (10758):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$R4HPk6oFVb-i-YR_PN9YE6kqx1I.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (10758):      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
E/flutter (10758):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/flutter (10758):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
E/flutter (10758):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
E/flutter (10758):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (10758):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/flutter (10758):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
E/flutter (10758): , null)
E/flutter (10758): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (10758): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter (10758): <asynchronous suspension>
```

this is the function inside controller

```
    public function newMessage(Request $request, $roomId)
    {
        $newMessage = new Message();
        $newMessage->user_id = Auth::id();
        $newMessage->room_id = $roomId;
        $newMessage->message = $request->message;
        $newMessage->save();
        broadcast(new NewChatMessage($newMessage))->toOthers();
        return response()->json($newMessage);
    }
```

this is the event class

```
class NewChatMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chat.'. $this->message->room_id);
    }
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'chat-event';
    }
}
```

channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('chat.{roomId}', function ($user, $roomId) {
    if(Auth::check()){ 
        return ['id'=> $user->id, 'name'=> $user->name ];
    }
});
```

In `Flutter` I use `flutter_client` package the following code is copied from it's documentation

```
Future<void> _initPusher() async {
    String token = await _store.read('token');
    try {
      pusher = PusherClient(
        "6f8...c3",
        PusherOptions(
          host: '10.10.10.251',
          encrypted: false,
          auth: PusherAuth(
            'http://10.10.10.251:8000/broadcasting/auth',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
            },
          ),
          cluster: 'eu',
        ),
        enableLogging: true,
      );
      channel = pusher.subscribe("private-chat.2");

      pusher.onConnectionStateChange((state) {
        print(
            "previousState: ${state.previousState}, currentState: ${state.currentState}");
      });

      pusher.onConnectionError((error) {
        print("error: ${error.message}");
      });

      channel.bind('chat-event', (event) {
        print(event.data);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I can successfully subscribe to public channel by bellow code.

```
Future<void> _initPusher() async {
    try {
      pusher = PusherClient(
        "6f8...c3",
        PusherOptions(
          encrypted: false,
          cluster: 'eu',
        ),
        enableLogging: true,
      );
      channel = pusher.subscribe("public-channel-name");

      pusher.onConnectionStateChange((state) {
        print(
            "previousState: ${state.previousState}, currentState: ${state.currentState}");
      });

      pusher.onConnectionError((error) {
        print("error: ${error.message}");
      });

      channel.bind('chat-event', (event) {
        print(event.data);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.

[Android Pusher AuthorizationFailureException: FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646714/android-pusher-authorizationfailureexception-filenotfoundexception)

removing the

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```

From your headers might do the trick.

Comment: actually i change content-type to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' , and its works , thanks to notice about this

Answer (score 0):

@usman fawwaz, I solved using `pusher_client` in Flutter. If you want to subscribe to a private channel init pusher as follow.

```
  Future<void> _initPusher() async {
    String token = await Store.read('token');
    try {
      pusher = PusherClient(
        pusherKey,
        PusherOptions(
          host: basePath,
          encrypted: false,
          auth: PusherAuth(
            basePath + "/broadcasting/auth",
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
            },
          ),
          cluster: 'eu',
        ),
        enableLogging: true,
      );
      channel = pusher?.subscribe("private-chat." + widget.room.id.toString());

      pusher?.onConnectionStateChange((state) {
        print(
            "previousState: ${state?.previousState}, currentState: ${state?.currentState}");
      });

      pusher?.onConnectionError((error) {
        print("error: ${error?.message}");
      });

      channel?.bind('chat-event', (event) {
        setState(() {});
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

for me the key point was; laravel by default has a route named `"broadcasting/auth"` I didn't know this.

Pusher itself made a package called  `pusher_channels_flutter: ^2.0.2` I want to switch to this package, here also I have subscription problem with private package.